# Power torque and rotational speed of a not running yet DC motor

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors, power-engineering

If the power $P = C\omega$, so how a DC motor powered by $P = 10\text{ W}$ can work as $\omega$ is of course 0 rad/s at first, because if $\omega = 0$, then $P = C\omega = C\cdot0 = 0$?

Comment: Oops, I meant torque (I said couple, french word for torque sorry)

Answer (score 1):

When $\omega = 0$ the motor is not doing any mechanical work, or producing any mechanical power, because nothing is moving. (If this is a long term situation, then the motor is *stalled*).

But when $\omega = 0$ the motor is still producing a *torque* (proportional to $I$) which causes a mechanical *angular acceleration* (by Newton's second law) and starts the system moving.

If the motor is stalled, the power $P = I * V$ mentioned by Solar Mike is converted into *heat,* not mechanical work - i.e. the motor is behaving exactly the same as an electrical resistor.

Comment: Oh okay thank you, but what is then the value of the torque ? Is that Intensity*(a constant of the motor) ? Something like C = I*k ?

Comment: Torque is force times distance ie moment...

Comment: I meant the torque of the dc motor at the startup, when  ω=0

Comment: do you know ? :)

Comment: Torque at startup or stall will be proportional to current and will depend on motor construction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_constants#Motor_Torque_constant

Answer (score 0):

Because Power is also

```
P = I * V
```

That is current (amps) and voltage, which is not zero.